# How to implement related list like contact via code

Tags: apex, related-list

I am trying to create a custom tab just like Accounts Tab.

I was able to fetch the detail on my custom tab.but I donot have any idea how i need to get the related list like contact which is related to the  record i am opening

My apex code is

```
<apex:page controller="ClassRetrieve" >
<apex:panelGrid columns="2">
<apex:form >
  <apex:commandButton value="New Account" action="{!NewAccount}"/>
  <p></p> 
<apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accs}" var="a">
    <apex:column headerValue="Name" >

                        <apex:commandLink value="{!a.name}" action="{!accountClicked}">
                          <apex:param name="nickName"
                                value="{!a.id}"
                            assignTo="{!recordId}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
      </apex:column>
   </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:panelGrid>
</apex:page>
```

My controller

```
public class ClassRetrieve {

Public string recordId{get;set;}
public List<Account> contactsInformation { get; set; }
public list<Account> accs {get;set;}

public ClassRetrieve()
{
    accs = [Select Id,Name From Account];
}

public pagereference accountClicked() 
{
    pagereference redirect = new PageReference('/apex/recordPage?id='+recordId);
    redirect.setRedirect(true);
    return redirect;
}

Public pagereference NewAccount()
{
    pagereference newAccpage = new pagereference('/apex/newAccount');
    newaccpage.setredirect(true);
    return newaccpage;
}
}
```

Page that displays the record is like

VF page

```
<apex:page controller="recordPageCont">  
create an custom email Field on account
  add edit / cancel buton <br/>
  add realted list using repeter eg Contacts using soql query
  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageBlockButtons >
       <apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!EditAccount}"/>
       <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!CancelButton}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  <apex:pageBlockSection >
     <apex:outputField value="{!objAccount.Name}"/>
     <apex:outputField value="{!objAccount.AccountNumber} "/>
     <apex:outputField value="{!objAccount.Type} "/>
     <apex:outputField value="{!objAccount.industry} "/>
     <apex:outputField value="{!objAccount.Rating} "/>
     <b>Email</b> {!objAccount.Name}@salesforce.com
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

apex is

```
public class recordPageCont {
public Account objAccount{get;set;}
Public string recId{get;set;}

    public recordPageCont ()
    {
         recId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
        objAccount =[SELECT Name, AccountNumber ,Type , Industry , Rating FROM account
                        WHERE ID = :recId ];
    }

    Public pagereference Editaccount()
    {
        Pagereference edtaccount = new Pagereference('/apex/editaccount?id='+recid);
        edtaccount.setredirect(true);
        return edtaccount;
    }

    public pagereference cancelButton()
    {
        Pagereference cnclbutton = new Pagereference('/apex/accountdisplay');
        cnclbutton.setredirect(true);
        return cnclbutton;
    }


}
```

please help..Any idea is welcome :)

Comment: You don't need custom controllers for any of this. You should read up on [Standard Controllers](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_controller_std.htm) and the `apex:relatedList` [component](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_relatedList.htm). None of the above requires apex.

Comment: Also make sure to add the inline edit functionality that will be an attracting features for your User group. <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton" event="ondblclick"/>

Comment: I want to create a related lisk with custom code @adrian Larson

Comment: Don't use Apex where you don't have to. Unless you have strong reasons not to, generally err on the side of using standard functionality. @AnkitaSingh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch related contacts within same query in "recordPageCont" class, the query can be modified to:-

```
    objAccount =[SELECT Name, AccountNumber ,Type , Industry , Rating, 
(select firstname, lastname from Contact) FROM account
                            WHERE ID = :recId ];
```

Also, I would suggest referring to other components provided by Salesforce

1. [apex:relatedlist](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_relatedList.htm)
2. [apex:enhancedList](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_enhancedList.htm)

To understand more about relationship queries refer to:-

- https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL.htm
- http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_workbook/Content/apex6_3.htm

Comment: I am getting an error for above query

" Didn't understand relationship 'Contact' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 8 column 21"

Comment: Can you check if your profile (being used for testing) has appropriate access to Contact object?

Comment: objAccount =[SELECT Name, AccountNumber ,Type , Industry , Rating, (select firstname, lastname from Contacts) FROM account WHERE ID = :recId ]; Please try the above query. The child relationship is Contacts instead of Contact

Answer (score 2):

Sans Apex:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:relatedList list="Contacts" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: @Sans Apex - pls let me know where to add this

Comment: This would be your whole `VisualForce Page`. Because it has an `Account` standard controller, you can add it as a button on `Account` or to the `Page Layout`.