# Display Children and Parent Records in Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a simple VF page displaying parent records just fine, but I cannot get the syntax perfect to display related child records. There are only 2 child records per parent records.

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.UtilJS}" />
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
   <apex:pageMessages />
<apex:pageBlock >

     //  Note: All modifications made on the page will be lost if 
     //  Return button is clicked without clicking the Save button first. 

   </apex:pageBlock>
   <apex:pageBlockButtons >
      <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
      <apex:commandButton value="Return" action="{!cancel}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selected}" var="a" id="table">
      <apex:column headerValue="Name">
         <apex:inputField value="{!a.name}"/>
      </apex:column>
      <apex:column headerValue="Hierarchy">
        <apex:inputField value="{!a.Type__c}"/>
     </apex:column>
     <apex:column headerValue="Status">
        <apex:inputField value="{!a.Status__c}"/>
     </apex:column>
 </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: this seems to be same as http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76861/how-to-implement-related-list-like-contact-via-code/76863#76863

Comment: Your code sample does not appear to do anything with child or parent records... Can you please explain where they are supposed to go?

Comment: No as of now it just displays Parent records...I'm just trying to add the relationship to display the 2 Child records underneath each Parent record

Comment: ohhh, are you trying to get them to show up in each row along with the parent records, like each row would have a sub-table of children? I'll warn you upfront, this is not simple and will likely not look as nice as you'd want it to lol  

That said, you should be able to accomplish this by nesting a repeat in each column to loop over the children and output some field values

Comment: Yes exactly! Man, I Honestly dont know how to write a nesting repeat and I Wouldnt  know where in the vf page to insert it...im a VF noob

Comment: I'll edit my answer with a basic stab at this :)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for accessing the child records (assuming they've been queried in as a sub-select from your main records) is fairly simple.
Let's assume your parent object is called `Custom_Obj__c`, the child records are called `Child_Obj__c`, and the relationship between them is called `children__r`. In this case, your controller should query in the main records with something like

```
[SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, name, other_field__c from children__r) FROM Custom_Obj__c];
```

Then on the VF side, you'd want to use a repeat (or another table) to loop over `{!a.children__r}`. Each row of this iteration will be one of the Child_Obj__c records.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selected}" var="a" id="table">
  <apex:column headerValue="Name">
     <apex:inputField value="{!a.name}"/>
       <apex:repeat value="{!a.children__r}" var="child" >
         <BR/><apex:inputField value="{!child.name}" />
       </apex:repeat>
  </apex:column>
  <apex:column headerValue="Hierarchy">
    <apex:inputField value="{!a.Type__c}"/>
       <apex:repeat value="{!a.children__r}" var="child" >
         <BR/><apex:inputField value="{!child.some_other_field__c}" />
       </apex:repeat>
 </apex:column>
 <apex:column headerValue="Status">
    <apex:inputField value="{!a.Status__c}"/>
 </apex:column>
```

Comment: Thanks for that RC! I bet that's right but I dont know how to implement it. Some background: I installed a free app and was able to edit the VF page to reference a custom object and a few fields but I Dont know how to edit the controller - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000018mbBEAQ